# Ask the user to enter multiple string responses at once in a numbered list. Input using the nextLine() method

Tags: java, return, overloading, java.util.scanner

Okay I made progress I think I was asking the wrong question but heres my new output;

- I get this(without bullets):

  - "Please list two external bodyparts on 2 difrent lines. \n"
  - bodyPart1
  - bodyPart2

I need this:

- "Please list two external bodyparts on 2 difrent lines. \n"

  - 1 > bodyPart1
  - 2 > bodyPart2

heres my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class secret{
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Please list two external bodyparts on 2 difrent lines. \n");
        String bodyPart1 = console.nextLine();
        String bodyPart2 = console.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your getting your strings in the main method why do you need to pass back?

Comment: What, exactly, do you expect your method `giveBack` to do? Because it won't.

Comment: @  brso05-because arbitrary requirements

Comment: It won't compile because,  for a given call,  a function can return only one value. And if you want a function to return some value, then it's return type should never be void. Further elaboration of your requirements would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're looking for, I see a couple problems with what you've provided. First, your giveBack() method has a return type of "void", which means it doesn't return anything, yet you are trying to return a String. Your method declaration should be
    public String giveBack(String string1, String string2){
    }
Second, as far as I know, you can't return two items by using two return statements. Once it hits the first return statement it will return the value and exit the method.

Comment: This should probably be a comment instead of answer, but I don't have enough rep here to comment yet. Also, I tried to use the code block formatting, but it didn't take.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong here. Let me see if I can explain each one:

1. As it was already mentioned, the giveBack method has a return type of 'void' yet, you are trying to return a String data type. This is clearly wrong.
2. The 'giveBack' method contains two return statements in the same block.  This is also wrong. The main purpose of 'return' is to return control back to the caller of the method. This means, the stack is popped and the address stored is returned to the Instruction Pointer. Additionally, if any value needs to be returned, it will do so as well.  Although a method could have multiple exit (return) points, only one per block is permitted. Having more than one return statement per block will result in a compilation error.
3. Your requirement of entering two items is very ambiguous.  The Scanner class contain multiple methods that could return a String object. For instance: next() and nextLine().  While the former returns the next complete token (from beginning of the string to the first white space), the latter returns an entire line.  You could say that a line could composed of multiple tokens.  In your context, one can assume that by "item" you mean line and not token.
4. You never use the giveBack method in your code
5. 'nextLine' is not a valid field or method of String. I am not sure why you are trying to invoke string1.nextLine (which will also result in a compilation error).  Besides, you are capturing two distinct lines in your code.  Why would you need to invoke again some sort of "nextLine" method?

If all you need is to display the two lines entered by the user, removing your giveBack method should fix your problem.  All you have to do:

1. Prompt user to enter two lines of text
2. Using the Scanner object, use the nextLine() method to capture both lines.  Like in your code, answer1 and answer2 are these two distinct lines.
3. Using System.out, display both of these lines to the screen.  If you want to create a method that takes care of displaying two lines of text, all you need is to create a show(String s1, String s2) method and put the System.out inside this method.  Then, simply invoke your 'show' method inside main.